# Responsive content div only

Tags: responsive-design

Okay so simply I have this layout consisting of two elements, a navigation ("left") and the actual site content ("right").

Now what I want is that the "left" div just stays like it is, but when downsizing the screen to a certain size, I would like the content div's width to decrease with it.

However, I have no idea on how to start. When I look up responsive web design I can only find skeletons for entire layouts with loads of divs and percentages but I just want this for one div only and I'm totally confused.

This is what I have right now:

```
.right {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 40px 0 40px 50px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.left {
    margin: 40px 0px 40px 40px;
    width: 210px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this http://jsbin.com/uquzaw/1/ isn't too overwhelming.

Essentially, you need percentages in your css and a meta tag in your html to get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for both the solutions, it works and the code looks pretty easy. Now I was wondering whether it is also possible to "start" at a fixed width (for example 700px) and than downsize the width if the window is being resized?

Comment: Do you mean you want the left side at 700px and then once the window gets to a certain size, the div will shrink to something like 500px?

Comment: Well actually I want the left side to be a fixed width in any case, but I already have that. I want what you say, but with the right side.

Comment: You could detect the width of the screen using media queries. In [this updated example](http://jsbin.com/uquzaw/2) I detect when the screen is _at least_ 900px wide, and add fixed widths to the `.right` and `.left` elements. Does this get you on the right track?

Comment: Well it works, but for some reason, my right content div is not 750px (like I said it should be in the css). http://jsbin.com/iqovuj/1 I put the relevant CSS on top.

Comment: Ah, your media query should go after your initial `.right` styles, http://jsbin.com/iqovuj/4. Media queries still fall under the "cascade" part of CSS, in that they can be over-written by a rule declaration further down in your styles.

Comment: Edit: wait there seems to be something a bit weird going on. The context div kind of "jumps" when the screen is less than 1050px wide. The width 52% (which was originally the correct size) is now suddenly "less wide" if you understand what I say. When I change this to for example 70%, it's about right, but then the context div immediately slides underneath the navigation. I tried changing a lot of width settings everywhere but I don't understand what seems to be the problem with this.

Comment: What do you mean by "jumps"? You are probably seeing the `.right` class slide under the `.left` class at smaller screen sizes right? That is because `.left` has a fixed with (a width set in px), so at some point `.right` cannot stay next to it because the screen is too small.

Comment: Well by "jumps" I mean that the width of the right div suddenly becomes like 200 pixels smaller when the screen size becomes less than 1050px. I know it's supposed to slide under the .left class, but when I change the width of the right class to 72%, this happens way too fast. http://jsbin.com/iqovuj/5 (though now there's no "jump" effect).

Comment: That is probably happening because the 52% width is a touch too small at < 1050.

Comment: Ah okay, I put it at 55% now and the width of the right div at 700px and it looks pretty good now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for isn't exactly responsive design. If I understand you correctly, you are going to need percentage widths.

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    <a href="#">Nav1</a> <br>
    <a href="#">Nav2</a> <br>
    <a href="#">Nav3</a> <br>
    <a href="#">Nav4</a> <br>
</div>

<div id="right">
    This is where the main content will go.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#left {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

#right {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```